# My binarySearch is returning me negative index even if I'm sure the item is in the arraylist

Tags: java, binary-search

**This is how I print it:**

```
     else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("I"))
     { 
        System.out.println("Enter item name to get price:");
        String n = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println( table.lookup_by_item(n) + "\n");
     }
```

**This is how I store the information and implement the binary search:**

```
public class LookupTable
{ 
private ArrayList<Item> Item_key; 
public LookupTable()
{

   Item_key = new ArrayList<Item>();      

}

public void read(Scanner in) {        

   String k = null, v = null;

  while(in.hasNextLine()) {
         k = in.nextLine();
         v = in.nextLine();
         Item_key.add(new Item(k,v));
         //System.out.println(k);
         //System.out.println(v);
     }
}   
public String lookup_by_item(String n)
{       
   Collections.sort(Item_key);     

   int index_found = Collections.binarySearch(Item_key, new Item(n, null));
   System.out.println(index_found);
   String itemn="";

   if(index_found >= 0) {

        itemn = Item_key.get(index_found).getValue();

}
return itemn;
```

**This is my item class:**

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item>
{
public String key;
public String value;

public Item(String k, String v)
{ 
  key = k;
  value = v;
}

public String getKey()
{ 
  return key;
}


public String getValue()
{ 
  return value;
}

public int compareTo(Item otherObject)
{
  Item other = (Item) otherObject;
  return key.compareTo(other.key);
```

**This is the content of the text file I want to do the binary search:**

```
Flat White
4.05
Cappuccino
4.45
Latte
4.45
Americano
3.35
Iced Coffee
3.25
Cold Brew
3.75
```

If I run it and search any random drink, the system will print out negative index_found. I tried to change return "key.compareTo(other.key);" to "0", but then it keeps returning me "3.35" regardless what I enter. "3.35" is the value of the item "Americano, 3.35".

Any smart coder, please teach me how can I get the value I want when I entered the key. Like when I enter "Cappuccino", I can get 4.45 returned.

Comment: I am unsure, but don't you need to override ```equals``` for the class ```Item``` for your binarySearch to return your specific element?

Comment: Unrelated comment: `(Item) otherObject` is redundant when `otherObject` is already of type `Item`. And a binary search shouldn't do `Collections.sort` every time it is called; that is slower than just doing a linear search. You should move that to the end of the `read` method.

Comment: @D.Lawrence I don't believe you need to override `equals` for `Collections.binarySearch`, the docs for that method don't say that the natural ordering has to be consistent with `equals`, and the implementation almost certainly delegates to the one taking an explicit comparator (which can't be assumed consistent with `equals`). That said, it could be worth a try anyway. The binary search algorithm definitely doesn't use `hashCode` at all, but if you override `equals` then you must also override `hashCode` to be consistent.

Comment: works for me!!!

Comment: FWIW your lookup_by_item code works for me, although I didn't use console input just `.lookup_by_item("Cappuccino")`. Do you need to trim any of the input strings for stray trailing whitespace / end-of-line characters? Can you trace out all of the strings you're checking in compareTo to make sure they are completely identical?

Answer (score 1):

I compiled and executed above code it working fine and gives correct answer. The only time it is returning **negative index value** when you `enter some key value which is not there in your ArrayList` i.e. **Item_key**. I guess there was some spelling/typo mistake you were making because of which it was returning negative index.

Comment: So if you type in "Cold Brew" to search, it returns "3.75“? Using the exact code I'm giving?

Comment: @ppp yes I have executed exactly the same code and it is working fine.